# How to use python flask routes with html

Tags: python, html, json, database, flask

So I'm working on a project using pythong flask, and sqlalchemy.

We have a datatablefull of contracts, that have the primary id of contract_id. I figured we have 2 different options of displaying the contracts.

option 1.
We have a generic view_contract.html template that makes a post request to an app route on flask and returns json of the contract to display on the page. However, I don't like this idea as much because then you can't copy and paste certain contract links to other people, since it will be the same generic webpage url

option 2.
We have an app route in flask that's @app.route(contract/< contract_id >/view) and we query the database to show that specific contract_id. However, I only know how to display the data in python using flask.jsonify. How can I generate html in the url as well?

tldr:

How do I generate a webpage such as contract/112431/view that loads the contract of id 112431 in an html form. As of right now I can only do it using python and that doesn't allow me to generate any of the html forms or details that I'd like

here's what I have right now... How would I add html to this page so it works for each contract

```
@app.route('/contract/<contract_id>/profile')
def view_suitor_profile(contract_id):
    cs = Contract.query.filter(Contract.contract_id == contract_id).all()
    cs_list = []
    for c in cs:
        con = {
            "con id": c.contract_id,
            "lcat" : c.lcat,
            "desired skills" : c.desired_skill,
            "mandatory skills" : c.mandatory_skill,
            "location" : c.work_location
        }
        c_list.append(con)
    return flask.jsonify(c_list=c_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean `I can only do it using python`? you are going to have to write some HTML if you want an HTML page.

Comment: I added some code to what I am using. I want to know how I can send that data and load an html template for each url with the contract id in it. It's to my understanding html is static, so it would load when u go to blahblah.html . So how do I get this to load html templates in a dynamic url with different ids each time

Comment: I know I can use js to make a call, but that would keep the url the same for every contract. I want the urls to be different so that people can share links to the specific contract

Comment: Is the `contract_id` the primary key id or is it another id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1

Use AJAX. Its easy to implement.

### Option 2

simple_contracts.py

```
@app.route('/simple/<contract_id>/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contracts(contract_id):
    result = dbs.Contracts.select().where(dbs.Contracts.id == contract_id).first()
    return render_template('contracts.html', result=result)
```

contracts.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>simple contracts</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if result %}
    {% for contract in result %}
        {{ contract.id }} <br/>
        {{ contract.name }} <br/>
        {{ contract.price }} <br>

{#  annotation: `contract` type object, have access in methods/attributes ex namedtuple  in jinja templates
    ex: in python: somelist = {'id': 12, 'name': 'contractIBM', 'price':1223 }
            access: somelist['id']

    in jinja: somelist.id => 12
            somelist.name => contractIBM etc...
#}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{#for send DATA in route use ahref args link or forms#}
<a href="{{ url_for('contracts', contract_id=123) }}"> Get info contract 123</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives an example of option 2.

In your view creating the list of data, instead of returning it as a json you should render a template with the data.

```
return flask.render_template("template.html",
                             c_list=c_list)
```

In your html you can loop through the list and extract all the elements

```
<div>
   {% for entry in c_list %}
      <p> Contract: </p>
      <p>{{ entry }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Then you can try and extract more detail from the `{{ entry }}` element by trying something like `{{ entry.lcat }}`

This allows you to create a html template which will be populated with the data that you pass along it, when calling `render_template`. So as long as you want the same layout, but with different data, this is one approach

Comment: Would the render_template not change the url?

Comment: I don't have access to test at the moment so that's why I'm asking. I've used that before but I don't remember if it changed the url or not

Comment: No, it does not. The url is defined in the @route decorator. `render_template` just means that you take an html-file + data, creates an html page which is then sent back to the user. So the only difference from returning the JSON data you are sending now and the new approach, is that the new approach will be a html formatted page, instead of JSON text

Comment: Awesome answer! thanks for going above and beyond with the explanation as well!